# OSX shell command for opening filename from file content?

Tags: macos, command-line

I'm new at experimenting with shell commands. I've written a small program that creates a new text file that is a template for a C++ header file. Then it copies the new file's path to a utility file we'll call f.txt.
I'd like to be able to click on a .command file on the desktop that runs the program then immediately opens the new file in the default editor, like so:

```
[execute my program];   //this part works
open [the path contained in the utility file f.txt]
```

I don't know the correct syntax for this to work; I was trying things like

```
less f.txt | open
```

but I clearly don't know what I'm doing, and don't know if there is a utility that can pipe content of a file into the open command...

Comment: First, the `open` command takes *arguments*, not *input* (see [this answer](https://superuser.com/questions/600253/why-is-xargs-necessary/600273#600273)); you need `xargs` or `"$( )"` (see [this one](https://superuser.com/questions/64792/xargs-vs-backtick)). Second, `less` is for interactively viewing a file; in scripts, use `cat` or just an input redirect (`< filename`). Result: `open "$(<f.txt)"`.

Comment: Thanks so much! I figured there was some sytax like that that I was missing.